# How to authenticate Google Cloud Vision via HTTP Request

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision via a rest http request using c#. As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth), I tried to authenticate with the api key as a parameter:

```
string uri = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" + API_KEY;
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
[...]
response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

However, I always get a 403 PERMISSION DENIED Code:

> Cloud Vision API has not been used in project XXXXX before or it is
>   disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXX
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Of course I checked, The API is activated, enabled and there are no API restrictions:
[image: API Key: No restrictions]

Since there seemed to exist [some problems](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/706) with that authentication method, especially with cloud vision, I tried authentication via an access token of a service account that I created. I gave the service account full access just to be sure that there is no issue with the rights of the service account:

```
string uri = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate";
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Still, same error message. Same goes with curl:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
-d "@{REQUEST_AS_JSON_OR_PATH_TO_JSON-FILE}" 
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key={API_KEY}
```

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out it is NOT sufficient to activate an API key (even when its without any restrictions), but one needs to actively go to the [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com) menu -> APIs and Services -> Library -> Search for "Cloud Vision" -> klick on the Cloud vision API and activate it. It takes a couple of minutes. The status of this is not shown in your dashboard.

Then, you can simply authenticate with the api key as URL parameter.